# instance creation failed: Required 'compute.images.useReadOnly'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp-iam

I have created a dedicated GCP project with images I want to share with people from other organizations.
I gave those people a custom role on the whole project with the following permissions:

```
compute.images.get
compute.images.getFromFamily
compute.images.list
compute.images.useReadOnly
resourcemanager.projects.get
serviceusage.services.get
serviceusage.services.list
```

But people have reported that they are getting the following error:

```
instance creation failed: Required 'compute.images.useReadOnly' permissions for <specific image>
```

I don't understand why they need that permission on the specific image when they have it on all the images of the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: I could imagine:
* You are using machine images, not (disk) images. Machine images do not contain the disk images IIRC.
* The error message may be incomplete and your organization may have policies against it. Could go to Cloud Console -> IAM -> Organization Policies and filter for “trusted image” so you see if you need to use trusted images?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue, it appears the GCP console made the operation when acting as a service account and not as the user itself.
That service account didn't have the attached role.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue, grant access for the service account wanting to use the custom image per the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images

Comment: Please, put the code into your answer. Links may die with the course of time.